# Redirect Broken links to Root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I had an app that was written in PHP and now the new app is written in Rails. They forgot to address bookmarked and browser cached pages so we still get a lot of hits on /index.php

How would I point that to the root on my rails app?

www.mydomain.com/index.php => www.mydomain.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use match in route for that
`match "/index.php", :to => "somecontroller#action", :via => "get"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the exception and redirect if the error code is 404.

See this railscast for full details:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/53-handling-exceptions-revised?view=asciicast

The basics are as follows.

Add this to your `config/application.rb` to route exceptions to your application:

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

Create an `errors_controller` and then map the errors to its show action in your `routes.rb` file:

```
match ':status', to: 'errors#show', constraints: {status: /\d{3}/ }
```

`errors_controller.rb`:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if request.path == '/404'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render text: request.path
    end
  end
end
```

Then render some sensible errors using your show template for those which are not 404 errors.

Answer (score 1):

put this after all other routes in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
matches '*any_path' => redirect('/')
```

This would match any given url and redirect it to `'/'`. But as long as this statement is last in `routes.rb` it won't be used for routes catched higher in file.